# VHDL casting a custom Type signed integer to a std_logic_vector

Tags: types, casting, vhdl

Hi I have a signal that is used in many places and subject to being altered down the track. So to simplify maintenance I have made a TYPE declaration called T_RowInt.

I have made two signals "typed" and "untyped" which both equate to an integer range -63 to 63 to demonstrate the problem.

Code follows:

```
type T_RowInt is range -63 to 63;
signal typed : T_RowInt;
signal untyped : integer range -63 to 63;

signal text_col : integer range 0 to 127 := 0;
signal bank : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "111";
signal page : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
```

I use the above in the following expressions:

```
addr_r_dram(19 downto 0)<= bank & page & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(typed,6)) & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(text_col, 7));
```

This fails syntax checking with "to_unsigned can not have such operands in this context"
However, this expression:

```
addr_r_dram(19 downto 0)<= bank & page & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(untyped,6)) & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(text_col, 7));
```

Is ok

Is there a way to force conversion of a custom TYPED signal?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Provide a [mcve], your snippets are confusing. All numerical types including your integer type T_RowInt are closely related, meaning values of the can be subject to *type conversion* to another integer type (e,g, `integer(typed)`, where `integer` is the base type of the index type of `unsigned`).  Note you'd also have todo some offset arithmetic to get it into the range of subtype `natural`. A type is a range of values and a set of operations. Some of those operations are predefined or *basic operations*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `type` then you have defined a completely *new* type as far as VHDL is concerned. However, how about using a *subtype*, eg

```
subtype T_RowInt is integer range -63 to 63;
```

then VHDL will not consider `T_RowInt` as being a completely different type. Your signal `untyped` is actually using a subtype, a so-called _anonymous subtype`:

```
signal untyped : integer range -63 to 63;
```

Perhaps you can see the similarity between these two lines of code?

Comment: A negative value of the base type `integer` is out of the `natural` range converted by package numeric_std function `to_unsigned` to composite array type `unsigned`. Use `to_signed` And type convert to `std_logic_vector` or add 63 to the `to_unsigned` first parameter. All three array type are closely related having the same element subtype (`std_logic`) and can be subject to type conversion. It appears the OP wants to add 63 to maintain DRAM address order. The snippets are unclear.

Comment: Sorry 'bout confusion. The application is very large and I thought just these lines would be enough info. Prior to conversion to a std_logic_vector all elements will be +ve and that's why I stripped the MSB (as will always be zero).  All said and done, Matthew's Answer confirmed my suspicion that the created TYPE is indeed alien to the conversion libraries and the use of SUBTYPE fixes that. :)